# How to list the sitecollections in a sorted manner

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, site-collection

I have written a powershell script for  listing the sites in a web app.

```
    $webapp=get-spwebapplication "https://my.comp.com"
    $allsites= $webapp.Sites
    foreach($msite in $allsites)
      {
        write-host $msite.rootweb.tile "---"- $msite.allwebs.count
      }
```

But how to sort this list with name or starting from smaller number of sites.

Answer (score 1):

```
$webapp = get-spwebapplication "https://my.comp.com"
$allsites = $webapp.Sites
$ht = @{}
foreach($msite in $allsites) {
    $ht.add($msite.Rootweb.Title, $msite.Allwebs.Count)
}
$ht.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Name
```